# Subset a data set based on first non-NA values

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a data frame like this:

```
 Year S1  S2  S3
 1699 1   NA  NA
 1700 5   23  5
 1701 6   1   6
 1702 7   13  9
```

I want to keep only those columns where the first non-NA year is equal or bigger than 1700. In this case, I want to keep columns `S2` and `S3` but not `S1` (since its first non-NA year is 1699).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `sapply` like this.

```
d[c(T, sapply(d[-1], function(x) d$Year[!is.na(x)][1]) >= 1700)]
#   Year S2 S3
# 1 1699 NA NA
# 2 1700 23  5
# 3 1701  1  6
# 4 1702 13  9
```

---

*Data*

```
d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Year S1  S2  S3
1699 1   NA  NA
1700 5   23  5
1701 6   1   6
1702 7   13  9")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Filter` :

```
result <- cbind(df1[1], Filter(function(x) 
              df1$Year[which.max(!is.na(x))] >= 1700, df1[-1]))
result
#  Year S2 S3
#1 1699 NA NA
#2 1700 23  5
#3 1701  1  6
#4 1702 13  9
```

Comment: Could I ask what does [1] and [-1] refer to here?

Comment: -1 removes the year column since you want to check this for S1 to S3 columns. To keep that column in final output I use `df[1]`.